# How to prohibit private includes to other libraries when using merged header placement

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy, include-what-you-use

I am in favour of merged header placement for a C++ project layout because
of several reasons also mentioned in the proposal [P1204R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html). Also I am trying to adhere to the [Pitchfork guidlines](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs).
I am using CMake to define the libraries and also the install step.

A merged header placement would look like this:

```sh
<root>/
    src/
        libA/      
            A.h. 
            A.cpp. # accidentially includes `libB/B-internal.h` or `libB/details/BB.h` !
            A-internal.h
        libB/
            B.h. # includes BB.h)
            B.cpp
            details/
                BB.h # is an internal 'libB'-only file but 
                     # gets installed because its needed.
            B-internal.h
```

One problem which I face is that, with merged header placement,

- one needs a special suffix to determine which headers are internal only and also won't get installed, in this case `-internal.h`.
- the other more important problem is that, `libA` when using and linking to `libB`, uses the include directory `<root>/src/libB` which makes developers able to accidentially include `#include <libB/B-internal.h>` which is really bad. The split header placement doesn't has this inherent problem (but still for `libB/details/Bb.h`).

I am wondering what ways do exists (maybe CMake, CI, clang-tidy? or by any other means) to somehow prohibit **inter-library includes to private headers** (because architecturally you really don't want this?)

The only way I see is, to write some scripts (not sure if [`include-what-you-use`](https://include-what-you-use.org/) can do this?) which could check **every** source/header file for potential such bad includes which is possible when you stick to a proper `libA/...` or `libB/...` include style.

Answer (score 0):

> am wondering what ways do exists (maybe CMake, CI, clang-tidy? or by any other means) to somehow prohibit inter-library includes to private headers (because architecturally you really don't want this?)

Move private include files into private directory.

```
├── libA
│   ├── include
│   │   └── A.cpp
│   └── src
│       ├── A-internal.h
│       └── A.cpp
└── libB
    ├── include
    │   ├── B.h
    │   └── details
    │       └── BB.h
    └── src
        ├── B-internal.h
        └── B.cpp
```

Add `include` dirs to includes and use `#include "B-internal.cpp"` inclusion style for internal files.

---

You would preferably do:

```
├── libA
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libA
│   │       └── A.cpp
│   └── src
│       ├── A-internal.h
│       └── A.cpp
└── libB
    ├── include
    │   └── libB
    │       ├── B.h
    │       └── details
    │           └── BB.h
    └── src
        ├── B-internal.cpp
        └── B.cpp
```

So that all includes for library named `libB` are inside direcotry `libB`. You may interest yourself in reading the whole sections around "Similarly, if we want to include hello.hpp from libhello..." from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html#src-dir you mentioned.

Comment: But this is no more merged header placement... this is split header placement...

Comment: > Header and source files (or module interface and implementation files) are next to each other (no include/ and src/ split). From the paper

Comment: Then, if you want to use it, you have to copy all files except the `-internal` into a directory and use that directory as include location. Either way, you have to have separate location.

Comment: and as mentioned: `libB/details/BB.h` can saddly still be included, but I think there is no way around it...